# Can't convert String onto integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

Following code return error "Can't convert String onto integer",  please help

```
subject = ['eng','Math','Sci']
grade = ['grade 1','grade 2','grade 3']
subject.each do |sub|
    puts ("some string")
    grade[sub] .each do |grd|
        puts ("some string")
    end
end
```

Comment: You're trying to index an array with a string. Did you want a hash instead of two arrays?

Comment: Could you add to your question an example output you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
  grade[sub] .each do |grd|
```

Ruby expects `sub` to be using an integer to reference a position in the list of grades.

Answer (score 3):

`grade[sub] .each do |grd|` thats the problem.

Array elements are accessed by using a index of [integer or a range of integers.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-size)

You are trying to access a array element by using the variable stored in `sub`. Since this is a ordinary .each loop it will loop all the elements in the array, in this case `'eng','Math','Sci'`. If you want the position of for example `'eng'` you could use a [`.each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

it should probably just be

```
grade.each do |grd|
```

with `each_with_index`  it would be

```
subject.each_with_index do |sub, index|
  print sub
  print grade[index]
end
```

If you want a subject -> grade collection it might be good to look into using a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) like Dave Newton said.

```
{"eng" => "grade 1","Math" => "grade 2","Sci" => "grade 3"}.each do |subject, grade|
  puts "#{subject| #{grade}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`subject` and  `grade` are both arrays. They can only be accessed by their position. In your `each` loop, the block gets the actual element (in `sub`), not the position. So in line 5, you are trying to access `grade['eng']`, which will not work and produces the error.  Note that unlike in e.g. PHP, an array and a hash (an associative array) are different things.

Guessing from your code, you might want to use `each_index` instead of `each` which will pass the index number to the block instead of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve; however, if you'd like to print subjects and grades and you're sure about the relative order of elements in the arrays, you could do this:

```
subject = ['eng','Math','Sci']
grade = ['grade 1','grade 2','grade 3']
subject.each_with_index do |sub, idx|
    puts "#{sub} - #{grade[idx]}"
end
```

Output:

```
eng - grade 1
math - grade 2
sci - grade 3
```

An hash is however probably more suitable to your needs.